# Importing a text file with i for imaginary numbers in Python

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I have a text file with imaginary numbers using i that I want to import into Python. The text file was saved from MATLAB which uses i for imaginary numbers and Python uses j for imaginary numbers. This is causing errors importing the file.

```
a = np.loadtxt('a.txt')
```

Here is an example of a couple lines in the text file:

```
282814803.000000 + 0.00000000000000i
-16531486.2042027 + 10391991.8573661i
6013078.93662147 - 7538432.00418058i
```

Comment: It is a common problem this (complex in python). Do you want to load the a.txt to a python list or numpy array. I posted an aswer for the "numpy array case"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One, quick and dirty way would be to do the following:

```
values = list()
with open('a.txt') as h:
    for line in h:
        values.append(eval(line.replace('i', 'j')))

# OUTPUT
# print values
# [(282814803+0j), (-16531486.2042027+10391991.8573661j), (6013078.93662147-7538432.00418058j)]
```

Answer (score 0):

here an example for one line :

```
>>> line="282814803.000000 + 163486.00000000000000i"
>>> line=line.replace('i', 'j')
>>> line=line.replace(' ', '')
>>> complex(line)
(282814803+163486j)
```

Then you can do :

```
list=[]
with open('data.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        line=line.replace('i', 'j')
        line=lim]ne.replace(' ', '')
        list.append(complex(line))
```

that will give you :

```
>>>list
[(282814803+163486.00468j), (-16531486.2042027+10391991.8573661j), (6013078.93662147-7538432.00418058j)]
```

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is the following but you need to preprocess the .txt file first.

If you open the txt file and replace (e.g.CTRL+H  on windows) all + symbols with just [space] and all i with [space] you will have something like:

282814803.0  0.00

-16531486.2  10391991.85

6013078.9  7538432.00

Then you can use:

```
import numpy
a = np.loadtxt('a.txt').view(complex)
print(a)
```

The results is:

```
>>> a
array([[  2.82814803e+08       +0.j        ],
       [  1.65314862e+07+10391991.8573661j ],
       [  6.01307894e+06 +7538432.00418058j]])
```

Maybe it is not the best way, but it works well and it gives you a numpy array not a list !